# PHP accessing protected key in object returns empty

Tags: php, object, woocommerce

I a writing a shipping plugin for WooCommerce, and when I try to get the values of a protected key ([key:protected]) it returns empty. How do we get the value of a protected key from an array or an object?

Specifically, in the calculate_shipping function of the woocommerce_shipping_init it passes in $package, which is an array which also contains some objects, and some of the object keys are protected. So $package looks something like this (this is a simplified version):

```
Array
(
    [contents] => Array
        (
            [abc123] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [data] => WC_Product_Simple Object
                        (
                            [object_type:protected] => product
                            [data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Carnal Seed CD and Study Guide - Oil Merchant Series
                                    [slug] => carnal-seed-cd-and-study-guide-oil-merchant-series
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

So the issue that when I try to get [name] or [slug], I get an empty value back for [data:protected] object (and therefore [name] and [slug] do not exist). For example:

```
$data = $package['contents']['abc123']['data']->data; // $data returns empty
```

So how do we get the value of a protected key from an array or an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protected properties cannot be accessed from outside of the object's internal context, much like private properties. What differentiates protected and private properties, however, is that an *extending* object may view the parent's protected properties, but not the private properties.

If you must access the protected properties directly for whatever reason, then extend the target object and provide a getter method:

```php
class MyExtendingClass extends WC_Product_Simple {
    public function getData() {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

With that being said, the class `WC_Product_Simple` should already extend a parent object that exposes a `get_data()` method. This may be what you're looking for. In that case, simply execute the following instead:

```php
$data = $package['contents']['abc123']['data']->get_data();
```

Answer (score 1):

B. Fleming has a better answer than this, but I still wanted to share what I figured out before I saw his response.

First I convert the object to an array. This takes `[key:protected]` from the object, and makes it a protected array key like this `[ * key]`.

The protected array key can then be accessed like this `$my_array["\0*\0key"]` (you must use double-quotes, as it does not work with single quotes).

So my solution was this:

```
$data_array = (array)$package['contents']['abc123']['data']; // Cast object to array
$name = $data_array["\0*\0data"]['name'];
```